# Edit a js div match div code that is has a different result on seperate link

Tags: javascript, php, html, height, current-page

The title might be confusing,

I have really bad js knowledge and therefore need help figuring this out.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".content_R").css({'height':($(".content_L").height()+'px')});
        $("#content_R").height($("#content_L").height() - 10);
        var highestCol = Math.max($('#content_R').height(),$('#content_R').height());
        $('#content_R').height(highestCol);
        </script>
```

This code above makes the div column_R equal to column_L's height.

It works perfectly but the admin link

```
edit-post.php?id='.$row['postID']
```

which displays a complicated cms editor...
seems to affect the script and make it 100px too short!
I want to keep this script included in the footer(which is on every page)
So I do not want to repeat the code again, again and again.

Is there a way to make the script below simply check
if the website is

```
edit-post.php?id='.$row['postID']
```

AND, if it is this change the code to:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".content_R").css({'height':($(".content_L").height()+'px')});
        $("#content_R").height($("#content_L").height() + 100);
        var highestCol = Math.max($('#content_R').height(),$('#content_R').height());
        $('#content_R').height(highestCol);
        </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

window.location.pathname would hold the path to the currently loaded script. You could check its value before running the rest of the js.